# How to avoid duplication in a dataflow beam pipeline in the writeToBq step?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We have a job working on Dataflow that ingests data from a Pub/Sub to write it to BigQuery. On a limited amount of data we were not having any duplicates but on our current volume 100 evts/s we have duplicates in the BigQuery tables. What we call here a duplicate is a row with the same event uuid.

Here is my code:

```py
class CustomParse(beam.DoFn):
    """ Custom ParallelDo class to apply a custom transformation """

    def to_runner_api_parameter(self, unused_context):
        return "beam:transforms:custom_parsing:custom_v0", None

    def process(self, message: beam.io.PubsubMessage, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam, window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
        import uuid
        data_parsed = {
            "data": message.data,
            "dataflow_timestamp": timestamp.to_rfc3339(),
            "uuid": uuid.uuid4().hex
        }
        
        yield data_parsed


def run():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--input_subscription",
        help='Input PubSub subscription of the form "projects/<PROJECT>/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION>."'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--output_table", help="Output BigQuery Table"
    )

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()
    additional_bq_parameters = {
        'timePartitioning': {'type': 'HOUR'}}

    # Creating pipeline options
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)

    def get_table_name(x):
        namespace = NAMESPACE_EXTRACTED
        date = x['dataflow_timestamp'][:10].replace('-', '')
        return f"{known_args.output_table}_{namespace}_{date}"

    # Defining our pipeline and its steps
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    (
            p
            | "ReadFromPubSub" >> beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub(
                subscription=known_args.input_subscription, timestamp_attribute=None, with_attributes=True
            )
            | "Prevent fusion" >> beam.transforms.util.Reshuffle()
            | "CustomParse" >> beam.ParDo(CustomParse(broker_model))
            | "WriteToBigQuery" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                table=get_table_name,
                schema=BIGQUERY_SCHEMA,
                additional_bq_parameters=additional_bq_parameters,
                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                batch_size=1000
            )
    )
    pipeline_result = p.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

What should we do to avoid this ? Are we missing a combining step ? For the record it has not happened following an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing some context (for example, you haven't included the `BrokerParsing` transform), but based on what you've included here, it seems like the issue might be that you're not including the `id_label` parameter in the `ReadFromPubSub` transform. According to the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.34.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub):

> **id_label** – The attribute on incoming Pub/Sub messages to use as a unique record identifier. When specified, the value of this attribute (which can be any string that uniquely identifies the record) will be used for deduplication of messages. If not provided, we cannot guarantee that no duplicate data will be delivered on the Pub/Sub stream. In this case, deduplication of the stream will be strictly best effort.

Comment: I have correctly renamed the class, sorry for this. However, what is weird to me is the fact that the duplicated event has the same uuid, whereas the uuid is only set up during the process method of the customParse. So if the event is processed twice each duplicate should have 2 different uuids ? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to `beam.io.WriteToBigQuery` [streaming_inserts](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.9.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.Method.html#STREAMING_INSERTS) guarantee

```
Use the BigQuery streaming insert API to insert data. This provides the lowest-latency insert path into BigQuery, and therefore is the default method when the input is unbounded. BigQuery will make a strong effort to ensure no duplicates when using this path, however there are some scenarios in which BigQuery is unable to make this guarantee (see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery). A query can be run over the output table to periodically clean these rare duplicates. Alternatively, using the FILE_LOADS insert method does guarantee no duplicates, though the latency for the insert into BigQuery will be much higher. For more information, see Streaming Data into BigQuery.
```